# Adobe Edge Animate & PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, adobe-edge

i'm working with Edge Animate and then would like to publish with `PhoneGap` and get my iOS app.

What action do i need to use to archive a tapping action on in iOS?

So if i'm using `touchstart` for example will that 'translate' in PhoneGap into taping?

Thank you!
-- Travis

Answer (score 1):

On Click or touch end  will work fine for tapping action in ios.
Paste the same code inside both the actions.
Regards,
Krunal

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
     $("#ID").bind('touchstart', function(){
        //your action
    });
```

to trigger actions, and yes, touchstart is way better than click for iOS!